# How to add formula in SQL Server and calculate the day of due?

Tags: sql-server, excel

I want to add the formula in one of my column in SQL Server named (Day to due). The formula will calculate how many days the equipment to reach the due date. I have used the formula in the excel but it can work successfully.The formula is (DueDate cell - Today()).

So i want to implement the formula in SQL Server . Anyone can help about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DATEDIFF`

in your example: `DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(),DueDate) AS Days_Until_DueDate`

A negative date will indicate the number of days a project is overdue.

As per MSDN from Microsoft https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Comment: thanks for your help. is there any way for me to put the formula in the properties? @Bad_Neighbor

Comment: My apologies but I do not understand what you mean by the "properties". The function DATEDIFF is a mssql function that will return the number of specified intervals (in this case, days) between two dates. If you want this to be stored data, I would heavily advise against it as this result changes daily (therefore should always be computed)

Comment: its okay. thanks. how this formula works? can you explain it? where to put this formula? @Bad_Neighbor

Comment: I use the formula and its work. but how to put this formula with other column?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the other column. This field (in our example, Days_Until_DueDate) would represent a field in the recordset from SQL. `DATEDIFF` takes the difference between the two dates provided and returns the result as the specified interval. Please review the MSDN page I had provided in the answer.